# Convert JulianDate to Time in milli second

Tags: java, android, date, time, julian-date

I know that if we want to convert Time in Milli second, then we should use the following function:

```
Time.getJulianDay(goToTime.toMillis(false), goToTime.gmtoff);
```

However, I want to know if I have a Julian Date Integer, then how would I convert it back to Time in Milli second? I searched the web and it seems there are no solutions for it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setJulianDay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#setJulianDay(int)) with `toMillis` to convert Julian date integer to time in `msec`. But remember converting from msec to julian day and then back msec won't give you the same result.